# API integration issue weathermap.org

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, api

```
res.write("<h1>The temprature in city is " +temp +"° celcius.</h1>")
```

Aboce code gives an output as follows

```
The temprature in city is 31.04Â° celcius.
```

I used the weathermap API to get the output first it was ok but later A started appearing.
How to remove the `Â` after temperature.

Comment: https://codepen.io/kumarmasterpraveen/pen/zYZBzOV

Comment: try this `res.write(\`The temprature in city is ${temp}° ${celcius}.\`)`